# Trying to get text to overlap circular image to behave upon resizing with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page where I'd like to have a row of circular images with text on them that can serve as links. I've figured out how to get this to work for the general case of a full sized webpage, but when I resize the width of the page, the text doesn't scale with the image because I have to use absolute positions. Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>


    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a class= href="">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="align-center img-responsive img-circle button-pic" />
                        <div class="button-caption">Button</div>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a class= href="">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="align-center img-responsive img-circle button-pic" />
                        <div class="button-caption">Button</div>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a class= href="">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="align-center img-responsive img-circle button-pic" />
                        <div class="button-caption">Button</div>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a class= href="">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="align-center img-responsive img-circle button-pic" />
                        <div class="button-caption">Button</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here's the main.css page...

```
body {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.button-pic {
  opacity: 0.4;
  position: relative;
}

.button-caption {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 87px;
    left: 85px;
}
```

I'd like to find a way to not have to set the top and left positions of the button-caption since not all of my labels will be the same length. Anyone have advice to offer?

Comment: Are you trying to place the text in the center of the image at all times?

Comment: Ideally, yes. If I remove the `left: 85px;` the `text-align: center;` doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your text position to remain consistent to the image you'll need to use percentages instead of setting a fixed amount of pixels for the position since the images are responsive.

See working Snippet.

```css
.content {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}
.button-pic {
  opacity: 0.4;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
.button-caption {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="content">

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="img-responsive img-circle button-pic" />
          <span class="button-caption">Just a Button</span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="img-responsive img-circle button-pic" />
          <span class="button-caption">Button</span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="img-responsive img-circle button-pic" />
          <span class="button-caption">Just a Really Very Pretty Long Label for a Button</span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="img-responsive img-circle button-pic" />
          <span class="button-caption">A Button</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch - this is awesome.

Comment: No problem and glad I could help.